# Simplest way to change target name (dll name) of vcpkg library

Tags: vcpkg

I want to use some vcpkg libs in an plugin to closed source 3rd party product (e.g. AutoCAD or ArcGIS).
Chosen vcpkg libs have zlib as dependencies, but the 3rd party product also use zlib and it is another version of the lib. I can not replace original dll, so the easiest way will be to change the name of vcpkg lib into e.g. myzlib1.dll.
How can I easy add prefix or suffix to target (dll) name in vcpkg?
Is there an easy way to do this for all libs, so I can build my own subset of vcpkg libs, which have my own name prefix or suffix and I'm sure that they make no name conflicts to other libs?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but complicated since not all ports are build with CMake. You need to define a custom `VCPKG_CHAINLOAD_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` with all the required changes to `CMAKE_(SHARED|STATIC)_LIBRARY_PREFIX_<LANG>` `CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES` etc. This should than cover all ports which are built with CMake. For the remaining ports you probably need to use the port overlay feature.

So the answer to the question: No there is no easy way to change the suffix/prefix for all vcpkg ports. In your case static linkage to your dependents is probably the easy way.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I have tried to do this, but without success. What I have done was simple modification of 
`scripts/cmake/vcpkg_common_definitions.cmake` file:

 `set(VCPKG_TARGET_STATIC_LIBRARY_PREFIX "itwh.vcpkg.")
set(VCPKG_TARGET_SHARED_LIBRARY_PREFIX "itwh.vcpkg.")
set(VCPKG_TARGET_IMPORT_LIBRARY_PREFIX "itwh.vcpkg.")
set(VCPKG_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES "itwh.vcpkg." "lib")`

unfortunately without any effect.

Comment: `scripts/cmake/vcpkg_common_definitions.cmake` is only for usage within vcpkg's portfiles and thus won't affect any CMake build done by vcpkg. For some ports you need to modify those so that the port finds the required dependent libraries but most ports don't use those variables (If there is not find_library call in the portfile it is probably not affected by the change). You need to modify the CMake build within VCPKG and this is done by using a `VCPKG_CHAINLOAD_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` and setting the variables mentioned in the answer.